# Redirect to original URL after login

Tags: angular, angular7, identityserver4, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

I am using Identity Server 4 with ASP.NET core 2.2, Angular 7 and [OICD-Client.js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js)

On the client application I am redirected to login after I try to access a protected route, for example:

```
/protected-route
```

After I login I am redirected to the Angular SPA application's callback:

```
/auth-callback
```

In the auth-callback route I complete the sign in:

```
export class AuthCallbackComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.authService.signinRedirectCallback();

  }

}
```

How can I get the original route, e.g., `/protected-route` and redirected to it?

If it is necessary for the answer I leave my configuration:

**Identity Server Configuration**

```
  services
    .AddIdentity<Use, Roler>(x => {
      x.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Context>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

  services.Configure<IISOptions>(x => {
    x.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
    x.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
  });

  services
    .AddIdentityServer(x => {
      x.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
      x.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
      x.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
      x.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
      x.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/login";
      x.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/logout";
    })
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.Resources())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.ApiResources())
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients())
    .AddAspNetIdentity<User>();
```

**Identity Server Resources, ApiResources and Clients**

```
public static List<ApiResource> ApiResources() {

  return new List<ApiResource> { 

    new ApiResource {
      Name = "api",
      DisplayName = "API Resource",
      ApiSecrets = { new Secret("Secret".Sha256()) },
      UserClaims = { JwtClaimTypes.Name, JwtClaimTypes.Email },
      Scopes = {
        new Scope { Name = "api", DisplayName = "API Recource" }
      }
    }

  };

} 

public static List<IdentityResource> IdentityResources() {

  return new List<IdentityResource> { 
    new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
    new IdentityResources.Profile(),
    new IdentityResources.Email()  
  };

}  

public static List<Client> Clients() {

  return new List<Client> { 

    new Client {

      ClientId = "spa",
      ClientName = "SPA Client",

      ClientSecrets = { new Secret("Secret".Sha256()) },
      RequireClientSecret = false,

      AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
      RequirePkce = true,

      AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
      AllowOfflineAccess = true,
      RequireConsent = true,

      AllowedScopes = { 
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile, 
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email, 
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
        "api" 
      },  

      RedirectUris = new List<String> { 
        "https://localhost:5001/auth-callback"
      },

      PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<String> { 
        "https://localhost:5000" 
      }

    }

  };

}
```

**Api Configuration**

```
  services.AddCors(x => {
      x.AddPolicy("AllowAll", y => y.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader());
    }); 

  services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(x => {
      x.ApiName = "api";
      x.ApiSecret = "Secret";
      x.Authority = "https://localhost:5005";
      x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    });
```

**Angular SPA Auth Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { UserManager, UserManagerSettings, User } from 'oidc-client';

const settings : UserManagerSettings = {
  authority: 'https://localhost:5005',
  client_id: 'spa',
  redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:5001/auth-callback',
  post_logout_redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:5001',
  response_type: "code",
  scope: 'openid profile email offline_access api',
  filterProtocolClaims: true,
  loadUserInfo: true
};

@Injectable({ 
  providedIn: 'root' 
})

export class AuthService {

  private manager = new UserManager(settings);
  private user: User = null;

  constructor() {

    this.manager.getUser().then(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });

  }

  isSignedin(): boolean {
    return this.user != null && !this.user.expired;
  }

  getClaims(): any {
    return this.user.profile;
  }

  getAuthorizationHeaderValue(): string {
    return `${this.user.token_type} ${this.user.access_token}`;
  }

  signinRedirect(): Promise<void> {
    return this.manager.signinRedirect();
  }

  signinRedirectCallback(): Promise<void> {
    return this.manager.signinRedirectCallback().then(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: What I see most people do is record the user's current page before you redirect them to identity server login. Be it localstorage or sessionstorage, then at your auth callback you would have `completeAuthentication()` and that is a promise type so you would just do your `router.navigate` to the value in your store.

Comment: This should be handled automatically by identity server 4.  All you have to do is set your return url on the client to {clientUrl}/signin-oidc

Comment: @JSon Yeah, but won't that be a static URL

Comment: How did you resolve the issue

Comment: How did you solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

In OAuth2 flow when you create a URL to the authorization server you can add `state` parameter. After user successfully logged in, the server will redirect to the specified redirect URL and add `code` and `state` as query parameters.

As an option when you create an authorization URL you can store in your backend the information regarding the original URL and add state with an ID of this information. When you receive the callback you can read the ID from `state` and return to your client where to redirect itself.

Or you can simply store the original URL in the state. ))

I use [openid-client](https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client), so I do not how to it oidc-client.js. `state` is a standartised parameter for this kind of cases described in [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1) - it must be there somehow.